# iphone - performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:' not found in protocol(s)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this inside a class

```
[delegate performSelector:@selector(doStuff:) withObject:myObject afterDelay:2.0];
```

and I am having this error

> warning:
>   '-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:'
>   not found in protocol(s)

I cannot figure out what may be wrong.

any clues?

thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your problem is that you've declared your delegate instance variable as:

```
id<SomeProtocol> delegate;
```

Right?  Well, that means that the compile-time checker is only going to look for methods in the `<SomeProtocol>` protocol.  However, `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is declared on `NSObject`.  This means that you should declare the ivar as:

```
NSObject<SomeProtocol> * delegate;
```

This is saying that it must be an `NSObject` that conforms to `<SomeProtocol>`, as opposed to any object that conforms to `<SomeProtocol>`.  This should get rid of your warning, and you don't have to do any casting.

Comment: @Dave I've probably learned more about Objective-C on SO from you more than anybody else! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't make sense to me. My protocol implements NSObject: @protocol CLSessionDelegate <NSObject> :-(

Comment: @Gonzalo: the `<NSObject>` protocol is not the same as the `NSObject` class.  The method in question is declared on the class, not the protocol, so extending the protocol won't make a difference.

Comment: So great! I thank you, and so do all the hairs I will now not pull out.

Comment: the bonus when changing from id to NSObject is that finally xcode is autocomplete properties of protocols. made my day.

Answer (score 3):

Try casting the delegate to its class' type first, then invoke `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`:

```
[(SomeClass *) delegate performSelector:@selector(doStuff:) withObject:myObject afterDelay:2.0];
```

Assuming that your `delegate` is of type `id`, you need to tell the runtime that the object in fact does inherit from `NSObject` (where the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method is defined) by casting it to it's class' type.

Comment: Any object will always inherit from NSObject (everything does, it is a root class). I think you mean conform to the NSObject protocol.

Comment: @Evan Everything does *not* inherit from NSObject. And `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is *not* defined in the `NSObject` protocol, it's defined in the `NSObject` class.

Comment: Casting breaks encapsulation.  What if this is for a class where the type of the delegate is unknown?

Comment: All objects excluding primitive data types in Objective-C inherit from NSObject. You are correct about performSelector:withObject:afterDelay, it is an instance method of NSObject.

Comment: @Dave Good point. I would go with your answer of declaring the delegate object as an `NSObject`.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski - then what does `NSProxy` inherit from?  (And before you answer, go read the documentation) :)

Comment: @Dave: NSProxy is not an actual object. It is basically a ghost or placeholder. (It does, however, conform to the NSObject protocol.)

Comment: @Evan `NSProxy` itself is abstract true, but it has concrete subclasses that do not inherit from `NSObject` (though they do conform to `<NSObject>`).  `NSProxy` is *another* root class in addition to `NSObject`. You can make your own root classes: `@interface Root { } @end`  The `NSObject` docs say "`NSObject` is the root class of **most** Objective-C class hierarchies" (emphasis added, note that it's not "all").

Comment: @Jacob Come to think of it, you *could* cast the `delegate` as `(NSObject *)`, and that would work, and would be acceptable.  :)  +1 for a valid solution

Answer (score 3):

Although the `NSObject *` cast Dave brought up will work, there's a cleaner alternate way that lets people use protocols as they would expect - you can have the protocol itself declare it supports the NSObject protocol.

NSObject is not just an implementation but also a protocol that includes all of the performSelector: method variants.  So you can simply declare in your protocol that you support NSObject like you would any other class supporting a protocol:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
```

And the compiler warnings will vanish (assuming you have imported the protocol definition).

Note that this does mean going forward anyone that declares support of your protocol would pretty much have to be an NSObject or inherit a lot of methods.  But all classes used in iPhone programming are derived from NSObject due to practical considerations, so that's generally not an issue.

EDIT:

It turns out the `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is not in the NSObject protocol (the ones without the delay are).  Because it's still nicer to everyone using your protocol if they can just use id to reference a protocol type, I'd still use a protocol to solve this - but you'd have to declare an extension to the NSObject protocol yourself.  So in the header for your file you could add something like:

```
@protocol MyProtocolNSObjectExtras <NSObject>
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
@end

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObjectExtras>
....
@end
```

Then you get all the same benefits as I described previously.

Comment: This wouldn't work in this case (I tried it), since the method in question is defined on `NSObject`, not `<NSObject>`.

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean - I saw that the protocol supported performSelector:withObject and assumed it also had the afterDelay: argument variant as well...  I would still use a protocol though, I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the delegate object to the actual class you are working in order to have the methods. Seen the delegate only can only show the methods defined in the protocol. performSelector:withObject: is not a method defined in the protocol.

```
[(CLASS*)delegate performSelector:@selector(doStuff:) withObject:myObject afterDelay:2.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2
    target:self 
    selector:@selector(doStuff) 
    userInfo:nil 
    repeats:NO];
```

Try that assuming you just want a timer